# In unsynchronized multi-threaded Java, can a String be in an unsafe, half-written state?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory

Assume code like this:

```
public class UsedByManyThreads {

  private String someString = null;

  // ...

  public String unsafeGetter() {
    if (someString == null) {
      someString = expensiveCalculationResult();
    }
    return someString;
  }

  // ...

}
```

If an instance of UsedByManyThreads is shared across many threads, and `unsafeGetter()` is called simultaneously, is it possible that some kind of half-written garbage data is returned?

For example...

Let's say someString is null and thread A starts to calculate the `expensiveCalculationResult()`.

Is is possible that `someString` becomes non-null, such that some Thread B comes along and returns a value that is not fully written?

I understand that multiple threads might end up calculating `expensiveCalculationResult()` in parallel, and then overwriting the `someString` member repeatedly.

But let's say that `expensiveCalculationResult()` always returns the same thing. Is there any danger in using code like this? Could `someString` somehow be malformed?

Comment: "is it possible that some kind of half-written garbage data is returned" No. The reference is written atomically.

Comment: Take a look on double-checking idiom.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking whether the reference itself will be malformed, or whether you mean it will correctly reference a partially-constructed String. But both are impossible. In the latter case, it's impossible because Strings only use `final` fields, which have special semantics in multithreading (well, a String's hashCode is cached in a non-final, unsafe way... but that works due to more subtle reasons, so for these purposes you can ignore it).